# Mac keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, powerpc

after my install on Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat on my iBook, I have noticed that used keyboard layout is a PC one, and not Mac one. Let me explain it more clearly :

As an example, Mac keyboard defines a physical key for the `-` (which sup character is `_`). When pressing this key, the character appearing on screen is `=`, as this key is binded using a Windows/Linux physical keyboard. To terminate with that example, for displaying the `-` character, I have to press the key displaying the 6 number (which on Mac should normally print `$`).

If I take a look at my configuration, the keyboard properties says (in its layout pane)

- language "other french"
- keyboard type "laptop mac"

What do I have to change to obtain the same key on screen than the one I have on keyboard ?

**UPDATE** It's an iBook G4 1.33 GHz (M9846LL/A: (Retail $999) 1.33 GHz; 12 in display; 40 GB hard disk; slot-load combo drive (DVD-ROM/CD-RW) - thanks, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBook#Models_3)) with a french localized keyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found several different links providing information about Apple's keyboard after install Ubuntu. From what I could see, you need to provide us more information about hardware model and keyboard model (In some countries the keyboard is localized).

I will include some pages I found here, just for documentation purpose. Don't forget: **edit your Ask and include your notebook model** too. Thanks!

- [AppleKeyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard)
- [MacBook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook)
- [mac keyboard configuration](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=362932)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu documentation solved a related problem for me. Every other solution I found was half baked or complex or no solution at all. You can find help [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard).